# Problem with running two functions async Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, asynchronous

I have a problem with a page for quite some time, I tried a lot of approaches, and never found a solution which satisfied me. Because of that I want to not even ask a question, I would also put my whole approach on stake. Let's start:
I found a typewriter function here on SO, which does this:

```
function type(srcText, link = ''){

        var i = 0;
        var result = srcText[i];
        interval = setInterval(function() {

            if((i == srcText.length - 1) ) {

                clearInterval(interval);
                $('#typing').append(link);
                $('.show_a').css('display','none').fadeIn();

                return;
            }
            i++;
            result += srcText[i].replace("\n", "<br />");
            $("#typing").html(result);
        },50);

        return true;
    }
```

I now use this function also to show a link for the text I'm posting. This works perfectly, if I pass no link, as well, if I only pass one set of text and link into the function. The moment I'm adding two sets of text and link, the whole thing crashes.

My first try was to chain the function callings (as I do it with Ajax Calls) and wait with one function for the other to be finished. I did it like that:

```
var test = function() {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
       type(text[0], link[0])

    });
    return promise;
};

var test2 = function() {
    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
       type(text[1], link[1])

    });
    return promise;
 };
```

I called it like that: `test().then(test2())` but both functions were called at the same time which caused an infinite loop.

I said that I want to put the whole approach on stake, which means, that I only want to keep the functionality. Means that the string should still be printed on the screen like a typewriter would do it. And after every line, before the 
, the anchorelement is inserted. I thought of passing the whole array of texts and links into the function and let the function check if it got an array or a string and then run either an foreach loop and print just one element after the other on the screen or run just the function as you see it above.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="tft" class="w-100 text-white">
    <p id="typing" class="w-100"></p>
</div>
```

The data I'm using looks like this (if it is an array, otherwise it's just a string):

```
var text = ['> text1 ','> text2'];
var link = ['<a class="show_a" href="http://link1" target="_blank">(click)</a>','<a class="show_a" href="http://link2" target="_blank">(click)</a>'];
```

Btw. if I use the "chaining" method, I would have to change the part, where the result is printed out to the screen. Because this is momentarily done by the html() method which causes the already printed out content to be overwritten when the second element of the array is passed in into the type() function.

Any of you have an idea or at least can point me into a direction? I'm kinda lost here. :(

Comment: Do you want both to print out? Or do you want one to print out, and then the other to replace it?

Comment: I want both to be printed out. I know that with the actual approach of handing in the print-sets one after the other I'm having the replace option. That's why I say I'm unsure what path to follow. :)

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say what exactly you are going for, but using promises you can have them go one after another with some minor modifications.

```js
var text = ['> text1 ','> text2'];
var link = ['<a class="show_a" href="http://link1" target="_blank">(click)</a>','<a class="show_a" href="http://link2" target="_blank">(click)</a>'];

function type(srcText, link = ''){
   // Return a promise that resolves when the link is completed
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var i = 0;
      var result = srcText[i];
      interval = setInterval(function() {
          if (i == srcText.length - 1) {
              clearInterval(interval);
              $('#typing').append(link);
              $('.show_a').css('display','none').fadeIn();
              resolve()
          }
          // This is modified so that it always appends instead of replaces
          i++;
          $("#typing").append(srcText[i])
      // I slowed this down so it is easier to see
      },500);
   });
}

// Call the first one
type(text[0], link[0])
// Once it's completed, start the second one
.then(function() { 
  type(text[1], link[1])
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tft" class="w-100 text-white">
    <p id="typing" class="w-100"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This way the promise works, thanks man! I didn't use the `.append` method because then I cannot have HTML tags anymore in the text. The browser would just print them out like this `<br>`, that's why I didn't want to use append. Any idea of how to get the HTML functionality back in? I could check for this `<` and append a full `<br>` but this would only allow one Tag to be usable in the input string.

Comment: I'm confused by your quesiton.

Comment: Let's say I have a string with pagebreaks in it. `['Text!<br>Text2<br>','Text3']` this couldn't be printed anymore.

Comment: That's a much trickier problem. You'd probably have to parse the string, turn the elements into DOM elements, iterate over the text elements, insert the rest. It's possible but more work./

Comment: At the moment I only need `<br>` in it, so I did it like this 

`if (srcText[i] == '<'){ $('#typing').append('<br>');i = i+3;}`

Ugly but for now it works. I though will work on the parsing when I got some more time. Thank you very much!